# Implicit typing discrepancy in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it true that TypeScript is supposed to implicitly type variable based on what is assigned to it? I am getting this strange discrepancy - if I implicitly type variable by assignment and call non existing method TS does not throw an error if this happened inside of a class but throws an error if this happens outside of a class:

```
class Bar {
    constructor() {
        //do nothing;
    }
}


class Foo {
    bar1;
    bar2: Bar;

    constructor() {
        //do nothing;
        this.bar1 = new Bar();
        this.bar1.asdasd();

        this.bar2 = new Bar();
        this.bar2.asdasd(); //error TS2094: The property 'asdasd' does not exist on value of type 'Bar'.
    }
}

var bar3 = new Bar();
bar3.asdasd(); //error TS2094: The property 'asdasd' does not exist on value of type 'Bar'.

var bar4 : Bar = new Bar();
bar4.asdasd(); //error TS2094: The property 'asdasd' does not exist on value of type 'Bar'.
```

See how bar1 does not throw an error? Check out this [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20nothing%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bar1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bar2%3A%20Bar%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20nothing%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar1%20%3D%20new%20Bar%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar1.asdasd%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar2%20%3D%20new%20Bar%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.bar2.asdasd%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20bar3%20%3D%20new%20Bar%28%29%3B%0Abar3.asdasd%28%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20bar4%20%3A%20Bar%20%3D%20new%20Bar%28%29%3B%0Abar4.asdasd%28%29%3B).

Comment: Your top snippet has several syntax errors and your second snippet does issue an error. ?. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20nothing%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0Afoo.asdasd()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error

Comment: Sorry, I was typing in a hurry, it is fixed now. No the second snippet does not issue any error;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in TypeScript infer their types from initializers, not from assignments. The `bar1` field in your class is of type `any` because it was not initialized and it does not have a type annotation. You can do anything with variables of type `any`.

Comment: If so then what is the difference then between the assignment inside and outset of a class in terms of initializers?

Comment: Inside/outside class does not matter. 'initialization' here means only one thing -- providing an initial value at the same place where a variable is declared, e.g. `var x = y;` for variables or `x = y;` in the body of a class declaration. Assignment (as a statement) is never initialization and does not affect type inference.

Comment: I see. For instance this: var bar3; bar3 = new Bar(); bar3.asdasd(); does not throw an error either. TIL how initialization works in TS. I  wish you guys best luck writing a bulletproof cook book :)